# Функция CSS rotate()

Tags: css

Не получается сделать то, что я хочу.
При наведении на пункт меню, хочу чтобы прокрутились на 360 значки возле меню.
При наведении на значки они крутятся, а вот если на пункт меню навести, то нет.
Как это сделать?

Код PUG

```
.main-menu
          nav.menu(role="Navigation")
            ul
              li
                a(href="#") Главная
                  img.menu-icons(src="img/menu-icons/home.svg", alt="")
```

Код SASS

```
.menu-icons:hover
    transform: rotate(360deg)
    transition: 1.5s
```

**Я много как пытался сделать, но получалось лишь при наведении на картинку крутится, либо же весь пункт меню крутится вместе с картинкой...**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: il:hover img.menu-icons{
    transform: rotate(360deg)
    transition: 1.5s}

Comment: Спасибо большое, как я и хотел :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте указать `hover` на ссылке, а стиль применять к её потомку

```
a:hover img.menu-icons { 
    transform: rotate(360deg); 
    transition: 1.5s;
}
```

```css
a:hover img.menu-icons {
  transform: rotate(360deg);
  transition: 1.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-menu">
  <nav class="menu" role="Navigation">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Главная<img class="menu-icons" src="https://s.cdpn.io/profiles/user/2784596/80.jpg?1547403031" alt=""/></a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: До этого я не додумался, может уже сплю, а может неопытный)
Ещё раз спасибо)

Comment: @hitFM пожалуйста, обращайтесь